# Let us say that we are picking 2 letters from a set of 12. How would you describe the sample space?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say the first letter is from the following set: {A,B,C,D,E,F}. And the second letter is from the following set: {a,b,c,d,e,f}. Would this be simply $12\choose2$=66? Or would it be $_{12}P_2=132$? I tried to do it out and got $6$ ways to do the capital letter, 6 ways to do the lowercase letter, and then multiplied by 2 since $Aa\neq aA$. This was $6\times 6\times 2=72$ which is not equal to the answers I got using permutations and combinations. Which way is the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \{A, B, C, D, E, F\}$; let $T = \{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$.  Then the sample space is 
$$S \times T = \{(s, t) \mid s \in S, t \in T\}$$ 
that is, the set of ordered pairs in which the first element is a member of set $S$ and the second element is a member of set $T$.  Since there are six choices for the first element and six choices for the second element, the number of such ordered pairs is $6 \cdot 6 = 36$.

Note that since the first element of the ordered pair is in set $S$ and the second element of the ordered pair is in set $T$, the outcome $aA$ is not a possible outcome.

The number 
$$\binom{12}{2}$$
represents the number of two-element subsets of a set with twelve elements.

You would get $72$ if you considered sequences of one uppercase and one lowercase letter if there were no requirement that the uppercase letter precede the lowercase letter.

Comment: That make sense. I should have been able to realize that. So it would be 72 if it did not have to be ordered. 
How would you find the probability that at least one is a vowel? Would you break it into 3 cases? 1 where the vowel is from S, another where the vowel is from T, and the third where there are 2 vowels?